# How to select a few rows of Running total

Tags: mysql, sql, date, window-functions, mysql-8.0

I have running total

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    DepositValue, 
    action_date,
    SUM(DepositValue)  OVER(ORDER by action_date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Running_total
```

The above select returns me the following:

```
id  action_date   DepositValue      Running_total
1   2020-04-01         20                20
2   2020-04-02         2                 22
3   2020-04-03         8                 30
4   2020-04-04         10                38
5   2020-04-05         14                48
6   2020-04-06         15                62
7   2020-04-07         22                77
8   2020-04-08         12                99
9   2020-04-09         4                 103
```

What i want to achieve is selecting only part of `Running_total` depend on `action_date` with already calculated values like this.

```
id  action_date   DepositValue      Running_total
3   2020-04-03         8                 30
4   2020-04-04         10                38
5   2020-04-05         14                48
```

Comment: Since, you are successfully using window functions, you must be running MySQL 8.0, not 5.7. I changed the database tag accordingly.

Comment: for id 3 running total is 30 fine, but how running total is 38 for id 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn your query to a subquery and filter in the outer query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        id, 
        DepositValue , 
        action_date, 
        SUM(DepositValue) OVER(ORDER by action_date) AS Running_total
    FROM mytable
) t
WHERE action_date BETWEEN '2020-04-03' AND '2020-04-05'
```

Note that window specification `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` is actually the default when not specificed, hence you can just remove it.

Also, your original query was missing a `FROM` clause, I added it.

Comment: . . Actually, the default window frame specification in MySQL (and I think all databases) is `RANGE BETEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`.  It doesn't matter if the sort keys are unique, but it can make a big different in other contexts.